# ROS-TCP-Connector C# Unity subscriber callback never fires

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to test the viability of the Ros TCP Connector library for Unity to displaying large point clouds.  I have created:
Added the `com.unity.robotics.ros-tcp-connector` library

I have created a PointCloudSubscriber game object that takes in a PointCloud2 message type.  i have configured by Ros1 connection through the Robotics tab, I am pointing to local host because I'm running the node locally.  I feel reasonably comfortable that it is properly connecting to ROS, it errors out when I pick a bad IP or port.  I've got logging messages for when the subscriber is created and when callbacks are executed and my callback is never triggered.

I am running the ROS Endpoint node.

Please let me know of any information I can provide beyond what I've said here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389811/ros-tcp-connector-c#-unity-subscriber-callback-never-fires/) by [jkovacich](https://answers.ros.org/users/88252/jkovacich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jkovacich](https://answers.ros.org/users/88252/jkovacich/) on 2021-11-02**:
moving to the "answers" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Success! I was able to work through my issues. I ran into a couple things that I had done wrong.

1. I had initially set the IP of the ROS connection to my ROS core node instead of the TCP Endpoint node. 2) I had created a ROS Connection game object and filled it with info, but then discovered the Robotics dropdown tab and had been using that. Under the hood my subscriber will still using the game object instead of the dropdown menu option. Reenabling the game object, and setting it to the TCP connection node instead of ROS master was enough to get things to work.

---

Originally posted by [jkovacich](https://answers.ros.org/users/88252/jkovacich/) with karma: 16 on 2021-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0